# Should we have programming added to no-no's in the Tour?

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons

I've just realized that the [SuperUser Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) doesn't list programming in the *Don't ask about...* list. I think we should consider adding it.

We have four migration targets for closed questions:

- Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- WebApps.SE
- Android.SE

Three of these have corresponding or overlapping list entries:

- Videogames, consoles, or other electronic devices, unless they connect to your computer (Android.SE, Ask Different and more)
- Websites or web services like Google, Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress (WebApps.SE)
- Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks (Server Fault)

However, Stack Overflow - the largest Stack of them all - isn't mentioned. I'm seeing programming questions posted every now and then, maybe we could direct some posters to SO in the Tour?

I suppose looking at migration statistics could be helpful, but I don't know how to access such data. I don't think such data is available in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/new).

Answer (score 1):

#### Maybe we could direct some posters to SO in the Tour?

**Some** programming questions are on topic, typically scripting languages like `cmd`, `bash`, `vba` and `powershell`, which does muddy the waters a bit.

Here are some statistics (for the last 90 days):

- Stack Overflow - 92 (around 1/day)

  - 18% rejected, but most of those are users who are question blocked on SO and decide to try their luck on SU
- Server Fault - 19
- Web Apps - 92 (around 1/day)
- Android - 51

I don't think these numbers warrant changing the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) page.